# Error en menu con funcion jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    lightbox.option({
      'alwaysShowNavOnTouchDevices': true
    });
    listapremier();
    $(function(){
                $('a').click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var div = $(this).data('href');
                        var y = $(div).offset().top - 70;
                        $('body,html').stop(true,true).animate({                                
                                scrollTop: y
                        },1000);
                });
        });
</script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style = "padding-bottom: 25px; padding-top: 25px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="titulogo"  style = "text-decoration: none" href="#"><img src ="img/logo.png"></img></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a data-href='#mycarousel' href='#'>INICIO</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-href='#nosotros' href='#'>NOSOTROS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  data-href='#servicios' href='#'>SERVICIOS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  data-href='#propiedades' href='#'>PROPIEDADES</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  data-href='#contacto' href='#'>CONTACTO</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" onclick="confiaprop()">CONFIANOS TU PROPIEDAD</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Registro/index.php" style = "background-color: #d5b560; color: black;">ÁREA DE INVERSIONISTAS</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

Todo funciona perfecto excepto por este boton:

```
                <li>
                    <a href="Registro/index.php" style = "background-color: #d5b560; color: black;">ÁREA DE INVERSIONISTAS</a>
                </li>
```

Es la única que tiene un enlace a otro index sólo me da error cuando inserto el script que tengo arriba en javascript, sin el script si funciona el boton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es por la función `e.preventDefault();` de tu javascript.

Te funciona bien con la mayoría de los enlaces del navbar porque están vacíos (no tienen `href` o este apunta a `#`) y la acción la resuelves mediante javascript. Pero el último enlace tiene un `href` bien definido, y el `e.preventDefault();` impide que se ejecute (preventDefault = "impedir la acción por defecto", es decir, seguir el href del enlace).

Tu opción sería distinguir de alguna forma los enlaces "normales" (con href) del resto de enlaces del navbar, y sólo estos últimos los manipulas mediante javascript.

Una manera de hacerlo sería modificar las etiquetas `<a>` del navbar (todas excepto la última) agregándoles una clase distintiva.

```
<a data-href='#mycarousel' href='#' class="item-menu">INICIO</a>
```

Y modificar el javascript para que se activen sólo los enlaces que tienen esta clase:

```
// $('a').click(function(e){           // Esto se elimina
$('a.item-menu').click(function(e){    // y se reemplaza con esto
```

Comment: Me funciono perfectamente gracias por tu ayuda :)